# NetBeans: Как определить новую подсветку синтаксиса и правила его валидации (на примере файлов .sass)

Tags: netbeans, sass, scss

В среде `NetBeans`, в меню создания файла под `Файл Sass` имеется ввиду файл с расширением `.scss`, в то время как упрощённый синтаксис расширения `.sass` данной средой не поддерживается. Для полной поддержки данного типа файлов необходима подсветка синтаксиса (подсветка от `.scss`, естественно, работать не будет), а так же валидация с выдачей сообщений о синтаксических ошибках.

Хотя у меня нет опыта в разработке для NetBeans, думаю за образец можно взять определения подсветки синтаксиса и правила валиации для файлов `.jade`: с `.sass` их объединяет объявление вложеннсти посредством отступов.

Где в файловой системе `NetBeans` мне найти определения подсветки синтаксиса `jade` и что ещё мне следует сделать для того, чтобы приступить к разработке поддержки разрешения `.sass`?