# NetBeans: Как редактировать меню создания новых файлов (конкретный пример)

Tags: netbeans, sass, scss

В среде `NetBeans`, в меню создания файла под `Файл Sass` имеется ввиду файл с расширением `.scss`, в то время как упрощённый синтаксис расширения `.sass` данной средой не поддерживается. Я бы хотел переименовать пункт меню `Файл Sass` в `Файл .scss`, а также добавить пункт `Файл .sass`.

Как создать новый тип файла, я уже знаю (Меню/Инструменты/Прочее/Файлы/Новый), но при создании нового типа файла он автоматически отправится в последнюю категорию меню добавления нового файла - `Прочее`. Мне же нужно `Файл .sass` нужно добавить в категорию `HTML5/JavaScript`. Как это сделать?

Вероятно, через опции это никак не сделать и потребуется редактировать вручную конфигурационные файлы. Если так, то какие именно файлы?

P. S. Для полноценной поддержки расширения `.sass` потребуется также правильная подсветка синтаксиса и его валидация. Естественно, и то и другое от расширения `.scss` в `.sass` корректно работать не будет. Но эта задача требует рассмотреия в [отедельном вопросе](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/729692/netbeans-%D0%9A%D0%B0%D0%BA-%D0%BE%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%B5%D0%B4%D0%B5%D0%BB%D0%B8%D1%82%D1%8C-%D0%BD%D0%BE%D0%B2%D1%83%D1%8E-%D0%BF%D0%BE%D0%B4%D1%81%D0%B2%D0%B5%D1%82%D0%BA%D1%83-%D1%81%D0%B8%D0%BD%D1%82%D0%B0%D0%BA%D1%81%D0%B8%D1%81%D0%B0-%D0%B8-%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%B2%D0%B8%D0%BB%D0%B0-%D0%B5%D0%B3%D0%BE-%D0%B2%D0%B0%D0%BB%D0%B8%D0%B4%D0%B0%D1%86%D0%B8%D0%B8-%D0%BD%D0%B0).